# grabbing content from a html page

Tags: javascript, html, titanium

I was wondering if there's a way to grab contents of a html file in titanium, just like with an xml file. For example with an xml file I could create a httpclient when I was grabbing content, like so:

```
var metaDataURL="some_xmlfile";
var xhr=Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

xhr.open('GET',metaDataURL);
xhr.send();

xhr.onload=function(){
    alert("loaded");
}

xhr.onerror = function(e) {
    alert(e.error);
};
```

The url I need information from is:

```
http://50.7.242.154:8070/7.html
```

All that's in there is some numbers and the name of a song and artist. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You use it the same way, you just GET-ting the file from the server. Essentially downloading.

```
var xhr=Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function(e) {
        var htmlresponse = this.responseText;
        // Do what you want with the HTML now
    }
});

xhr.open('GET','http://50.7.242.154:8070/7.html');
xhr.send();
```

Comment: thanks for your response. The code I provided above was producing an error: 'The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response'. When I switched the url to 'http://apple.com/', it worked. Furthermore, when I manually keyed in the url to the phone's browser, it worked as normal. It has been suggested to me that Android has an issue when there is a port number in the URL and that is the source of the error. Have you had any experience with this?

Comment: Did you put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in your manifest / tiapp.xml?

Comment: No. Will try this now

Comment: should it be within the android tag, like so: 
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</android>

Comment: I have created http clients before without adding that line andd had no issue. Also I'm using webviews in my app also. Not sure if that's related. The code I provided above didn't make a difference. Would I have to put manifest tags within the android tags?